# Bootsrap 3.x.x VS Alpha 4 - Wizard Broken

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have made a bootstrap 3.3.1 wizard using Bootply. The site I want to embed the bootply test wizard to runs Bootsrap 4.0 and it makes the wizard break, is the wizard function non existent in Bootsrap 4.0? As it looks and works completely different in 3.x.x to 4.0 Alpha...

How can I make it look like it does in boostrap 3.3.1..

If you fork the bootply you can change the bootsrap version

http://www.bootply.com/51bhZhTCtS

Comment: Bootply question: how do you change BS version in an existing Ply? (I'm not logged, I've the same view as you'd have in another browser than your main one)

Comment: Hi, its on the left hand side, i believe you have to be logged in. thanks

Comment: Hi, i copied another snippet, how can i find what classes I need to change...Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "wizard" function in either version. Since v4.x is still in "alpha" the class names are still changing, This tool may help:

http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/

Also the JS script is still working, but needs to be migrated to 4.x along with the HTML markup for the steps. For example, the first input was in a column too small to make the input clickable. Also, nested `col-*` should always be placed in another `row` instead of directly in another `col-*`

http://www.codeply.com/go/Jwct9dUGk4

Comment: Thank you that has really helped me.